# How to pass value to directive in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-directive

### Code & Explanation Updated

I want this directive to disable or enable based on boolean value but whatever value (true/false) I sent through isDraggable variable, in both the cases, directive is enabled.

What to improve in this code?

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[movableObject]'
})
export class MovableDirective extends DraggableDirective {
  @Input() movableObject: boolean;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-panel',
  template: `<div [movableObject]="isDraggable"></div>`,
  styleUrls: ['./panel.component.scss'],
})
export class PanelComponent implements OnInit {
  private isDraggable: boolean = true;
}
```

Comment: the error is pretty clear, your directive has no (input) property called `movableObject`

Comment: can you show me short example as an answer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass values to directive in angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43124998/how-to-pass-values-to-directive-in-angular)

Comment: like @Jota.Toledo said you are missing the binding part, if you want to pass the value to directive you need to use the `@Input` decorator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice the @Input decorator. It adds metadata to the class that makes the directive's movableObject property available for binding.

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[movableObject]'
})
export class MovableDirective extends DraggableDirective {
   @Input() movableObject: boolean;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-panel',
  template: `<div [movableObject]="isDraggable"></div>`,
  styleUrls: ['./panel.component.scss'],
})
export class PanelComponent implements OnInit {
  private isDraggable: boolean;
}
```

Comment: I wont deny your opinion, but I gave what OP asked for .. a short example with explanation why it wasnt working.. but downvoting wasnt necessary IMO

Comment: @vinayakj I have applied the stated solution but get no result. once I send isDraggable=false, and then I send it as true but both times the result was same. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: plz update your question with new code & expected behavior

Comment: ahh that.. try `template: <div [attr.movableObject]="isDraggable"></div>,`

Comment: It seems Directives cant be added/removed dynamically as angular needs to know the directive before compiling the template.In case above code doesnt work, So you may try `<ng-container *ngIf="isDraggable"><div [movableObject]="isDraggable"></div></ng-container><ng-container *ngIf="!isDraggable"><div></div></ng-container>`,

Comment: @vinayakj, do we need to pass the directive selector in html as <div [movableObject]="isDraggable"  movableObject></div>. Please update your answer, if it is missing.

Comment: no need, its already there as `[movableObject]`, it act as both directive selector & input binding property.