# Using Directive to listen for touch events

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-directive

I have this directive:

```
constructor(private el: ElementRef, private control: NgControl) { }

@HostListener('input')
@HostListener('keydown')
setClass(): void {
    if (this.control.errors && this.control.touched) {
        this.el.nativeElement.classList.add('border-danger');
        this.el.nativeElement.classList.remove('border-success');
    } else if (this.control.value && this.control.touched) {
        this.el.nativeElement.classList.add('border-success');
        this.el.nativeElement.classList.remove('border-danger');
    }
}
```

Using directive in input:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" validatorClass id="inputNomeEmpresa" formControlName="nomeEmpresa">
```

But when I trigger through the form with: `this.form.markAllAsTouched();`

I can't capture by any touch event.

Answer (score -1):

The `control: NgControl` is your DOM element. In the case of reactive forms, `markAllAsTouched()` marks the `formControl` as touched not DOM element.

To achieve this you need to pass your formControl in directive and check on that control. in this case it would be `[validatorClass]="formGroup.get('nomeEmpresa')"`

You can refer to this answer for how to pass input in directive.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45609562/7088848

Comment: But how can I hear the input changes?